# How to connect wordpress user with my own APP user?

Tags: users, login, third-party-applications

I want to add my woocommerce store into my APP. (The APP and website in the different servers.)

How can I connect the users' data? Sync the users statue? Like when I login on APP, I was also login in the store? And after I register on my website, I can login on APP no need to register again.

Comment: What's APP? I can't think of an APP.

Comment: The APP is for smart home control. Now we want to add our store into the APP.